# Wordpress - $wpdb->insert - MySQL NOW()

Tags: wordpress

is there any possibility to use the MySQL NOW() in the $wpdb->insert call?

When I use the following code, NOW() is not working.

```
$data = array(
        'id' => NULL,
        'order' => serialize($_POST['data']['Order']),
        'created' => NOW(),
        'user_id' => $current_user->ID
    );

$wpdb->insert(ORDERS_TABLE, (array) $data );
```

Comment: Just do `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Comment: I thought about that one and tried it too. It works, but I get the time in GMT and not the time it should be. NOW() does the job right...

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I believe the canonical approach is to use the WordPress `current_time()` function passing it 'mysql' as the first parameter to specify a mysql timestamp compatible format (the alternative is UNIX timestamp format)  and '1' as the second parameter to specify GMT time (default is local), like this:

```php
$data = array(
    'id' => NULL,
    'order' => serialize($_POST['data']['Order']),
    'created' => current_time('mysql', 1),
    'user_id' => $current_user->ID
);

$wpdb->insert(ORDERS_TABLE, $data);
```

`current_time('mysql', 1)` outputs `2012-07-18 12:51:13`.

More here: [http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_time/)

Comment: Right, `current_time('mysql')` is what WP uses internally as well when saving posts or pages.

Comment: @coderabbi Passing `1` or `true` as the second parameter for `current_time` returns UTC/GMT, default is blog's local time.

Comment: current_time('mysql') or the newer wp_date() function works, but doesn't give microseconds that now(6) does? Would really like wpdb insert method to support native SQL functions - maybe using another formatting character than %s in formats array? Resorting to wpdb query with insert statement including escape for each value except now(6)...

Comment: Does this use the database as the Authoritative time source.. eg what is 'now' on the wordpress installation could be different to what is 'now' on the database, for example if the database is hosted on a different server

Answer (score 7):

For anyone using Wordpress 5.3 and above, [the recommended approach](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/09/23/date-time-improvements-wp-5-3/) is to now use [wp_date](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_date/), not current_time.

```
wp_date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 3):

As word "created" means that you only need the "NOW()", current date and time, on insert. You can alter the field created

```
 ALTER TABLE `ORDERS_TABLE` CHANGE `created` `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

and don't use created field at all in query, so your new query will look like..

```
$data = array(        
    'order' => serialize($_POST['data']['Order']),        
    'user_id' => $current_user->ID
);

$wpdb->insert(ORDERS_TABLE, (array) $data );
```

and when you run your query "created" will take default value, it will be equal to NOW(), you may have noticed that I have omitted "id" as well it will also get its default value, I assume that it is auto incremented field.

Answer (score 1):

At present this is still not clear that you can pass these SQL functions like NOW() easily using the `$wpdb->insert()` method within the WordPress `$wpdb` class.

Short of writing a class to extend the `$wpdb` class, the most straightforward way I can see is to use the `$wpdb->query()` method and write some code to convert your `$data` array to an SQL string to pass to the method.

```
$sql = sprintf( 
    'INSERT INTO table (id, order, created, user_id) VALUES (%d, %d, %s, %d)',
    $data[id], $data['order'], $data['created'], $data['user_id'] 
);

$wpdb->update( $sql );
```

More here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score -3):

It's an old topic, but I found a silly solution for using NOW() outside SQL statements and it works:

```
$mysql_now = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT NOW() as dbNow", ARRAY_A );
echo $mysql_now['dbNow'];
```

You are welcome.