# insert current datetime to custom wordpress datetime column

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, datetime

I have an issue with inserting current datetime to custom wordpress datetime column. I've used `curent_time` function I also used `date('Y-m-d H:m:s')` as value for the column but it did not work.

I will provide my code for any suggestions:

```
global $wpdb;
$load_rec_table = $wpdb->prefix.'load_rec';
// Insert into load record table
$wpdb->insert($load_rec_table,array(
    'rec_date' => current_time('mysql'),
    'total_load' => $_POST['totalPower'],
    'total_gap' => $_POST['totalGap'],
    'carriage' => $_POST['carriage']
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use NOW() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() functions of Mysq**l

```
global $wpdb;
$load_rec_table = $wpdb->prefix.'load_rec';
// Insert into load record table
$wpdb->insert($load_rec_table,array(
    'rec_date' => NOW(),
    'total_load' => $_POST['totalPower'],
    'total_gap' => $_POST['totalGap'],
    'carriage' => $_POST['carriage']
    ));
```

Comment: I got this error when I use NOW() function "Fatal error: Call to undefined function NOW()"

Comment: **Yous can refer below link:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566603/wordpress-wpdb-insert-mysql-now 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time

Comment: As I mentioned in my question description I've used current_time function and I've got nothing inserted in my table and I've seen this question before I post mine

Answer (score 0):

rec_date' => current_time('mysql',1),

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).